# How to delete the filename?

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

I want to delete the last 5 words of the filename, then i want to give so other filename.\

Code.

```
Name FileName As NewFileName
```

The above code is working for rename, but i don't want to rename, i want to delete the last 5 letter of the filename.

Expected Output

Filename

```
sufeshcdk.txt - I want to take (sufeshcd) only
Modifyulla.txt - I want to take (Modifyul) only
```

How to do this?

Need VB6 Code Help.

Comment: "5 words" or "5 characters" (your examples seem to imply the latter)?

Comment: if you are replacing with Modifyul how the char 'a' adds in last Modifyula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
private function RemoveLast5(FileName as string) as String
    if len(FileName) > 5 then 
        RemoveLast5 = left$(FileName, Len(FileName) - 5)
    else
        RemoveLast5 = FileName
    end
end function


dim FileName as string
FileName = "Modifyulla.txt"

dim NewFileName as string 
NewFileName = RemoveLast5(FileName)

Name FileName As NewFileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this is the basic idea...

```
FileNameLength = Len(FileName)
NewFileName = Mid$(FileName, 1, FileNameLength - 5)
Name FileName As NewFileName
```

edit: fixed the syntax per below comments.

Comment: Showing Error as "invalid procedure call or argument". I gave the Filenamelength = myfilename

Comment: NewFileName = Mid$(FileName, 1, FileNameLength - 5)

Comment: At what line does it give an error? Also, don't forget `Len()`.

Comment: I've correctly changed the code , just one comment above :-) VB6 Mid function expects 1 as the start position not O